# Gulp task to read multiple JSON files and merge in to one

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, gulp

I have a folder which has multiple JSON files which hold array of objects.

```
Folder A
  file1.json
  file2.json
  file3.json
```

The content of each file is the same (single array of multiple objects).

I want to be able to run a gulp task to read each json file, copy the objects from the array and create new file, with the content being a single array of objects (the objects have to be from all the json files in Folder A)

Comment: Did you try [gulp-merge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-json)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three plugins:

- [gulp-merge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-json)
- [gulp-jsoncombine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsoncombine)
- [gulp-json-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-concat)

Comment: Thank you. These are ideal.